# Using jni4net to use Native DLL function in java and getting System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: java, dll, jna, jni4net

I am using `jni4net` to use the DLL function in Java.

Using jni4net-0.8.6.0-bin I compile using the command:

`.\proxygen.exe "D:\sampledlls\sample_interface.dll" -wd "D:\hope"`

On executing this command , getting the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\sampledlls\sampledll.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

I also used JNA library to use the DLL function in java. But in that as well I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'sampledll': The specified module could not be found.
```

Here is my code for JNA:

```
public class hellodll {
    public interface dcmInterfaceDLL extends Library {
        public void DCM_InitializeFields();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); 
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path",
            "C:\Users\320035705\Downloads\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\sampledlls");
        dcmInterfaceDLL sdll = (dcmInterfaceDLL) 
        Native.loadLibrary("sample_interface", dcmInterfaceDLL.class);

        System.loadLibrary("sample_interface");

       sdll.DCM_InitializeFields(); 
    }
}
```

This is a native.dll.

How can I load my DLL?

Comment: Can you please post the exact code you are using (both `jni4net` and `jna`)? It's possible it's a simple string escaping of slashes situation.

Comment: @DanielWiddis posted the code for jna and jni4net!

Answer (score 1):

For the `jni4net` version, it properly found the dll but it is in the wrong format.  It is possible that you are using a 32-bit JVM with a 64-bit DLL, or vice versa.  You might try adding `/32BIT+ /force` switches to the `proxygen` command line.

There may be other problems with the DLL as the error message mentions its dependencies.  Your comments indicate an error message associated with Visual C++ runtime package.

---

For the JNA library loading, you are not finding the DLL due to improper escaping of backslashes.

In Java (and many other languages) the backslash (`\`) is an escape character.  When used in a String it has special meaning, such as (`\n`) for a newline.

In your String representing the path, you have not escaped the backslashes, so the String `"C:\Users\320035705\Downloads\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\sampledlls"` ends up being interpreted as `"C:Users320035705DownloadsJNAHelloWorldMWrobelJNAHelloWorldMWrobelsampledlls"`.

Use two backslashes (`\\`) to represent a single backslash in a Java String.  If you specify your path like this, it should work for JNA:

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path",
    "C:\\Users\\320035705\\Downloads\\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\\sampledlls");
```

However, if there are issues where the DLL requires another dependency, this could fail for the same reason.

Comment: even after setting it with two backslashes , i am getting the same error.

Comment: It is a 32 bit dll, in the IIS manager i enabled Enable 32-bit application as  True, despite that i am getting the error while using jni4net

Comment: i tried to run the dll using the command  "rundll32.exe  sample_interface.dll,DCM_InitializeFields". getting the error The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail

Comment: That means you need the Visual C++ runtime package.  See [this link](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/solved_the_application_has_failed_to_start_because_its_side_by_side_configuration_is_incorrect_error.html)

Comment: that error got resolved. but getting another error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\320035705\Downloads\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\JNAHelloWorldMWrobel\sampledlls\sample_interface.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Comment: What are the dependent libraries to the DLL?  Are they installed and on the path?